# Real-Time Figure Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have an rgb matrix `rgb = imread('Map.jpg');`
I'm changing its pixel colors in a `while` loop. Is it possible to see the changes real-time?

I'm tested this script, but not working!

```
rgb = imread('Map.jpg');
figure
image(rgb);
axis image;
while (conditions)
    pause(0.001)
    % Change rgb matrix
    drawnow
end
```

Comment: Does it work if you set a breakpoint in your while loop and run it step by step?

Comment: Also, what function do you call in order to plot your data? (if it's something alog the lines of imshow, you should call it once before your loop and attach a handle to it, then only update its Cdata in your loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image command places an image on the figure from the rgb matrix. If you change the matrix after using the image command the figure will not change. Try calling `image(rgb)` after you change the matrix but before the `drawnow` command